# 3D Artist needs a Python Coder

Tags: python, python-3.x, camera, usb

I'm a 3D Artist who is building a Scanner with a Raspberry Pi.
So i was rebuilding this Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eAYxnSU2aw&t=456s&index=1&list=FLYWYYsrGevtpxQa1mWJ5AGA

But i get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imageCapture.py", line 54, in <module>
    gp(clearCommaned)
NameError: name 'clearCommaned' is not defined
```

Here is the Code:

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from sh import gphoto2 as gp
import signal, os, subprocess

def killgphoto2Process():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()

    for line in out.splitlines():
        if b'gvfsd-gphoto2' in line:

            pid = int(line.split(None,1)[0])
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)


shot_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
shot_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
picID = "PiShots"

clearCommand = ["--folder", "/store_00020001/DCIM/100AZ365", \
                "-R", "--delete-all-files"]

triggerCommand = ["--trigger-capture"]
downloadCommand = ["--get-all-files"]

folder_name = shot_date + picID
save_location = "/home/pi/Desktop/gphoto/images/" + folder_name

def createSavFolder():
    try:
        os.makedirs(save_location)
    except:
        print("Failed to create the new Directory.")
    os.chdir(save_location)

def captureImages():
    gp(triggerCommand)
    sleep(3)
    gp(downloadCommand)
    gp(clearCommand)

def renameFiles(ID):
    for filename in os.listdir("."):
        if len(filname) <13:
            if filename.enswith(".JPG):
                os.rename(filename, (shot_time + ID + ".JPG"))
                print("Renamed the JPG")
            elif filename.enswith(".CR2"):
                os.rename(filename, (shot_time + ID + ".CR2"))
                print("Renamed the CR2")

killgphoto2Process()
gp(clearCommaned)
CreateSaveFolder()
captureImages()
renameFiles(picID)
```

For me as a 3D Artist this is deep stuff. But i just can't find the Error. Maybe somebody could be so nice and help me out?

Greetings
Philipp

Comment: It's a typo. You called the variable `clearCommand`, and tried to reference it with `gp(clearCommaned)`.

Comment: Yeah you spelt command wrong instead of commaned its command

Comment: Reading the error message in this case would have been very helpful and probably save you the time you spent asking a question here.